# React.js: Best practices for API's grouping

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been using Angular for 3 years. I have created some small and big projects. In every project, I have used proper folder structure for API calls(which many resources suggest). Below is a simple example

constants.ts

```
export const uploadData = `${url}/uploadData`;
```

service.ts

```
 uploadData(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(constants.uploadData, formData);
  }
```

And in the component file, I import the service and call the API like this

```
this.service.uploadData(formData).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res) => {
      // do something
});
```

I specify all my related APIs and services in respective folders and call them wherever I need them. It's been 5 months since I started learning React and ReactNative. Now I am comfortable with both I started doing a major project. Now, the resources I followed to learn React didn't follow the proper structure(Create the API in whichever folder is required and call it with fetch/axios). Found some resources that follow structure but not effectively like how I did it in Angular. I can't find any resources with the requirement. It would be helpful if I can get one example of how we can have the folder structure like in Angular so that I will follow the good approach, instead of ending up writing bad code. (I am using Axios)